# What is the significance of the flowers that are placed on a student's desk after they leave Black class?

Tags: riddle-story-of-devil

So far on the series, every time a student is transferred out from Black class, different flowers are put on that student's desk the next morning.

[image: Flowers left for Otoya Takechi on episode 3] [image: Flowers left for Kouko Kaminaga on episode 4]
[image: Flowers left for Haruki Sagae on episode 5] [image: Flowers left for Shiena Kenmochi on episode 6]
[image: Flowers left for Hitsugi Kirigaya and Chitaru Namatame on episode 7] [image: Flowers left for Suzu Shutou on episode 8]
[image: Flowers left for Mahiru/Shinya Banba and Isuke Inukai in episode 10] [image: Flowers left for Sumireko Hanabusa in episode 11]

Are these all flowers that really exist?
If so, what are their names and their significance?
And if not, what are they supposed to imply about each character?
**What is the significance of each different kind of flower for each of the girls?**

Comment: The top right flower is a red spider lily. In the manga, Suzu says they mean "I'm looking forward to meeting you again," though other sources indicate it means "abandonment" or "lost memories." The bottom left one seems to be verbena flowers.The top left one seems to be a pair of white Angel's Trumpets.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, they are actual flowers. And according to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/akuma_riddle/status/457892343354765312) from the anime's
official Twitter account, the *hanakotoba* ([花言葉](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8A%B1%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89), literally "flower
words") that are hidden behind each flower have some relevance to each
character.

> **See also:**
>   [What is the relation between the flowers and the heroines in ED sequence of Photokano?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4132)

So far, the names of the flowers and their implied meanings have been stated
in the manga or by the anime staff in response to viewer questions.

---

#### Otoya Takechi

- [ヤマユリ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%83%A6%E3%83%AA) (*[yamayuri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilium_auratum)*, lit. "mountain lily") / 「人生の楽しみ」
  (*pleasure of life*) <sup>1</sup>

  [image: yamayuri]
  <sup>[Photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lilium_auratum1.jpg) by Wikimedia Commons user KENPEI /
  [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sup>

#### Kouko Kaminaga

- [彼岸花](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%92%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90%E3%83%8A)<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup> ([red spider lily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycoris_radiata))

  - 「また会う日を楽しみに」<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup> (*looking forward to
    seeing you again*)
  - 「悲しい思い出」<sup>2</sup> (*sad memories*)

  [image: red spider lily]
  <sup>[Photo](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/89747904@N00/499897) by Flickr user kenji mori / [CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)</sup>

#### Haruki Sagae

- [バーベナ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%99%E3%83%8A) ([verbena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbena)) / 「家族の愛」 (*family's love*) <sup>3</sup>

  [image: Verbena tenera]
  <sup>[Photo](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/tanaka_juuyoh/2589452958/) by Flickr user TANAKA Juuyoh / [CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)</sup>

#### Shiena Kenmochi

- [アザミ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B6%E3%83%9F) ([thistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thistle)) / 「復讐」 (*revenge*) <sup>4</sup>

  [image: Japanese thistle]
  <sup>[Photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cirsium_japonicum_3.JPG) by Wikimedia Commons user Qwert1234 /
  [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sup>

#### Chitaru Namatame

- 赤[バラ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%A9) (red [rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose)) / 「愛情」 (*love*) <sup>4</sup>

#### Hitsugi Kirigaya

- 白バラ (white rose) / 「無邪気」 (*innocent [childlike]*) <sup>4</sup>

#### Suzu Shutou

- 赤い[チューリップ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%97) (red [tulip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip)) / 「恋の宣言」 (*declaration of love*)
  <sup>5</sup>

#### Mahiru/Shinya Banba

- [ヒルガオ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%92%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AC%E3%82%AA) (*hirugao*, Japanese [bindweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calystegia)) / 「[絆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kizuna)」 (*bond
  [human ties]*) <sup>6</sup>

  [image: hirugao]
  <sup>[Photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Calystegia_pubescens2.jpg) by Wikimedia Commons user KENPEI /
  [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sup>
- [ヨルガオ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AC%E3%82%AA) (*yorugao*, [moonflower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea_alba)) / 「妖艶」 (*seductive*) <sup>6</sup>

  [image: yorugao]
  <sup>[Photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ipomoea_alba1.jpg) by Wikimedia Commons user KENPEI /
  [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sup>

#### Isuke Inukai

- 赤い[カーネーション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3) (red [carnation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dianthus_caryophyllus)) / 「愛を信じる」 (*believe in
  love*) <sup>6</sup>

#### Sumireko Hanabusa

- [アイスランドポピー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%99%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%92%E3%83%8A%E3%82%B2%E3%82%B7) ([Iceland poppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papaver_nudicaule)) / 「慰め」 (*comfort
  [consolation]*) <sup>7</sup>

  [image: Iceland poppy]
  <sup>[Photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Papaver_nudicaule_dsc00913.jpg) by Wikimedia Commons user David.Monniaux /
  [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sup>

---

**References**

<sub>1. [悪魔のリドル (2)](http://www.kadokawa.co.jp/product/321310000132/), ISBN 978-4-04-121056-7</sub>
<sub>2. https://twitter.com/akumariddleQA/status/460430373109788672 from
[the Q&A after episode 4](http://togetter.com/li/660159)</sub>
<sub>3. https://twitter.com/akumariddleQA/status/462962907437735936 from
[the Q&A after episode 5](http://togetter.com/li/662989)</sub>
<sub>4. https://twitter.com/akumariddleQA/status/468363714454773761 from
[the Q&A after episode 7](http://togetter.com/li/669431)</sub>
<sub>5. https://twitter.com/akumariddleQA/status/470574398374551552 from
[the Q&A after episode 8](http://togetter.com/li/671908)</sub>
<sub>6. https://twitter.com/akumariddleQA/status/475654677640384512 from
[the Q&A after episode 10](http://togetter.com/li/677839)</sub>
<sub>7. https://twitter.com/akumariddleQA/status/478499435496747008 from
[the Q&A after episode 11](http://togetter.com/li/681073)</sub>

Comment: Good job, Yamanaka Yibe

Answer (score 1):

It's a sign that the girl is 'gone' and not just absent.

The flowers on a desk usually means that the student is dead. However in the anime, it could mean that they were kicked out or worse, executed.

Comment: Yes, this I could understand. I edited my question to make it clearer that what I want to know is how *each* particular flower relates to *each* particular girl.

Comment: Flower meaning = Their personality or probably just a unique random flower placed by the author in order for the viewers to know their differences.